# Why won't this javascript hot/cold app run?

Tags: javascript, function

added a while loop, and trying to end the loop by entering finish inside the loop. The game is still running after it the game is completed.

```js
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;  // generate random #
var guess;
var guessCount = 0;
var correctGuess = false;
var diff;

var correct = false;
while (!correct) {
    correct = guessFunction();
    var finish = false;
}

function guessFunction(){

    guess = prompt('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100. What is it?');

    guessCount += 1;

    var guessInt = parseInt(guess);  //turn guesses into interger

    if (guess == number){           //which number is bigger, guess or number
        alert('Correct!' + 'That was a total of ' + guessCount + ' guesses.');  
        correctGuess = true;
        finish = true;
    } 
    else if (guessInt > number) {
        diff = guessInt - number;
    } 
    else if (guessInt < number) {
        diff = number - guessInt;
    }

    if (diff >= 1 && diff <= 10 && !correctGuess) {
        alert('Very Hot');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 10 && diff <= 20 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Hot');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 20 && diff <= 30 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Warm');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 30 && diff <= 50 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Cold');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff > 50 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Ice Cold');
        guessFunction();
    }

}
guessFunction();
```

Trying to get this code to run but it only allows for 2 alert windows when guessing the random number. Im not sure how to get this to run, perhaps the guessFunction is not running?

```js
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;  // generate random #
var guess;
var guessCount = 0;
var correctGuess = false;
var diff;

function guessFunction(){
guess = prompt('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100. What is it?');
guessCount += 1;

var guessInt = parseInt(guess);  //turn guesses into interger

if (guess == number){   //which number is bigger, guess or number
 alert('Correct!');  
} 
else if (guessInt > number) {
 diff = guessInt - number;
} 
else if (guessInt < number) {
 diff = number - guessInt;
 }
}
guessFunction();

if (diff >= 1 && diff <= 10) {
 alert('Very Hot');
        guessFunction();
} 
else if (diff < 10 && diff <= 20){
 alert('Hot');
    guessFunction();
} 
else if (diff < 20 && diff <= 30){
 alert('Warm');
    guessFunction();
} 
else if (diff < 30 && diff <= 50){
 alert('Cold');
    guessFunction();
} 
else if ( diff > 50){
 alert('Ice Cold');
    guessFunction();
}
```

Comment: Look into using looping structures, like `while`.

Answer (score 1):

The script stops executing because you only call your function twice. If you want this to run until the user guesses the right number, you probably want a while loop:

```
var correct = false;
while (!correct) {
  // guessFunction could return true if they get it right
  correct = guessFunction();
}
```

Comment: I added the while loop now im having a problem with the prompt continuing to pop up after the game has ended. I even put finish = true within the first for loop.

Comment: Do you have a for loop in your code? Do you need to update your question or something? I don't see it there...

Comment: Okay, I see your update now. It has a few problems. First, you're calling guessFunction in your while loop, which means you should remove all of the calls to guessFunction from inside of guessFunction itself. You can leave the alerts in if you want. Second, you don't need the finish variable. Simply return true from guessFunction and the game will end because your while loop is going while "correct is false", to use plain English. Last, remove the call to guessFunction at the very end of the script, it's not needed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your script is only executing twice before exiting.  You've got your nesting wrong:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;  // generate random #
var guess;
var guessCount = 0;
var correctGuess = false;
var diff;

function guessFunction(){

    guess = prompt('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100. What is it?');

    guessCount += 1;

    var guessInt = parseInt(guess);  //turn guesses into interger

    if (guess == number){           //which number is bigger, guess or number
        alert('Correct!');  
        correctGuess = true;
    } 
    else if (guessInt > number) {
        diff = guessInt - number;
    } 
    else if (guessInt < number) {
        diff = number - guessInt;
    }

    if (diff >= 1 && diff <= 10 && !correctGuess) {
        alert('Very Hot');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 10 && diff <= 20 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Hot');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 20 && diff <= 30 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Warm');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff < 30 && diff <= 50 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Cold');
        guessFunction();
    } 
    else if (diff > 50 && !correctGuess){
        alert('Ice Cold');
        guessFunction();
    }
}
guessFunction();
```

**EDIT:**

My answer is more verbose than it needs to be so that it relates directly to your question.  The next step for you is to implement the better solution of a while loop mentioned in Menello's answer in your script.

Comment: I also want to point out that OP's original code (and this answer) will call `guessFunction()` over and over, creating a much larger call stack (using up more resources) than is needed. Best practice would definitely be to convert it to use a loop.